# Issue with union function of igraph

Tags: r, graph-theory, igraph, subgraph

I tried using the union function on 2 graphs which where inducted subgraph of the same graph G (so there was no conflict among them).
My problem is the original graph (and the subgraphs) are weighted, on the other hand the union of those subgraphs is not.

This is the code i created the subgraphs with (weights can assume a value in {1, 2, 3, 4, 5}:

```
weights <- E(g)$weight
graphs <- list()
for (r in seq(5)) {
  graphs[[r]] <- delete.edges(g, E(g)[weights!=r])
}
 
reduced_graphs <- list()
x <- numeric(5)
y <- numeric(5)
for (r in seq(5)) {
  reduced_graphs[[r]] <- delete.vertices(graphs[[r]], V(graphs[[r]])[degree(graphs[[r]])<=-1])
  
  y[r] <- length(get_users(reduced_graphs[[r]]))
  
  reduced_graphs[[r]] <- induced_subgraph(reduced_graphs[[r]], c(sample(get_users(reduced_graphs[[r]]), y[r]^sqrt(4.3/10)), get_movies(reduced_graphs[[r]])))
    
  x[r] <- length(get_movies(reduced_graphs[[r]]))
  
  reduced_graphs[[r]] <- induced_subgraph(reduced_graphs[[r]], c(sample(get_movies(reduced_graphs[[r]]), x[r]^(4.3/10)), get_users(reduced_graphs[[r]])))
  
  reduced_graphs[[r]] <- delete.vertices(reduced_graphs[[r]],  V(reduced_graphs[[r]])[degree(reduced_graphs[[r]])==0])
}
```

And this is the code that gives me an issue:

```
reduced_graph <- igraph::union(reduced_graphs[[1]], reduced_graphs[[2]])
is_weighted(reduced_graph)
[1] FALSE
is_weighted(reduced_graphs[[1]])
[1] TRUE
is_weighted(reduced_graphs[[2]])
[1] TRUE
```

It also turn out that the vertex of the resulting graphs lost their other attributes as well (like type and color):

```
V(reduced_graph)$type
NULL
V(reduced_graph)$color
NULL
```

Does anyone know how to fix the issue? Thankyou!

OS: Windows 10 pro
Rstudio
igraph version: 1.2.6

---

[Cross-posted on StackOverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/69044932/695132)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you can try the following workaround

```
graph_from_data_frame(
  unique(
    do.call(
      rbind,
      lapply(reduced_graphs, get.data.frame)
    )
  )
)
```

Comment: Thankyou, I really liked your idea and indeed the resulting graph keeps the weights, tho it doesn't solve the issue it had with the vertex attributes that get lost even with this solution. (Also correct me if I am wrong but I believe the unique is unnecessary since the subgraphs have no common edge)

Comment: @David Could you use `dput()` to share your data? Then I will check with it.